# Word for hiding "all other layers" in graphics design

Tags: terminology

In audio engineering, you use the *solo* function to listen to only one mixer channel, and *mute* to listen to everything expect the current channel. What is the corresponding terminology in graphics design?

For *mute*, *hide* is an appropriate term, but what is the corresponding term to *solo*.

Comment: Are you asking about software, "What is the term for bringing one layer or object to the front so it obscures everything else?" This question is probably better asked elsewhere (it can be migrated); but to determine that, more detail is needed.

Comment: The function that does this in Inkscape is called “show/hide other layers”. I’m not sure that there’s a single word equivalent.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, sort of yes, but I am not asking about a layer that obscures everything else (that is a mask as mentioned by WeatherVane). Rather a solo function is usually used by an audio engineer to temporarly disable every other channel (as if they did not exist), to tweak settings for that particular channel.

Comment: Ok, so can you describe what you mean in a graphic design context rather than an audio context? What action(s) would you do, that you need a single word for?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Temporary hide all other layers, so only the "solo" layer becomes visible.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest **mask**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mask) has

> **mask**
> NOUN
>
> **6** *Photography*
> A piece of material such as card used to cover a part of an image that is not required when exposing a print.

The entry does say *photography* but one of its example usage sentences is

> The Unsharp Mask is an old photography trick that has become available to ‘the common man’ through the introduction of digital editing tools.

**Mask** is also used as a verb.

Comment: Doesn't "mask" imply that it has the specific purpose of going in between? The "solo" button on the mixing console, is usually left up in the final mix (otherwise, you have recorded a lot of tracks you did not need).

Comment: I posted this answer because 'mask' is a term used in digital imaging, not because it is an exact equivalent of the audio situation.